# How to apply page break for images in MS Word VBA (Macro)?

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, page-break

I developed a MS Word Macro for this situation:

---

Summary:

An excel file has 3 columns namely Image Path which holds the local file path of the image, Product Name which contains product name values and Product Link which contains the online store link values of each product.

The contents in the excel file are placed in the word document.

- The image using the image path is placed to the left of the document at the beginning.
- Then, the product name and product link are placed to the right of the image.
  -The image has text wrapping enabled with square wrapping style to wrap the texts to its right.
- Both the product name and product link text use Calibri font and size 14
- Some spacing formatting

---

---

The following is my code:

```
Sub CreateNewWordDocument()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Dim excelWorkbook As Object
    Dim excelWorksheet As Object
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cumulativeTop As Single
    Dim imageHeight As Single
    
    cumulativeTop = 0 'Initializing cumulativeTop
    
    ' Create Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        ' If Word is not running, create a new instance
        Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    
    ' Make Word visible (optional)
    wordApp.Visible = True
    
    ' Create a new Word document
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    
    ' Create Excel application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If excelApp Is Nothing Then
        ' If Excel is not running, create a new instance
        Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    
    ' Open the Excel file
    Set excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\virtu\Desktop\Product Details 3.xlsx")
    Set excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
    
    ' Find the last row with data in the Excel sheet
    lastRow = excelWorksheet.Cells(excelWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(-4162).row ' -4162 represents xlUp
    
    ' Loop through the rows in Excel and add content to Word document
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming headers are in the first row
        
        
        Set image = wordDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=excelWorksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
            Width:=-1, Height:=-1)
            
        
        With image:
            ' Set text wrapping for the image
            .WrapFormat.Type = 0 ' Square wrapping style
            ' Set image position
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Left = 0
            .Top = cumulativeTop
            .Width = 150 ' Adjust the width as needed
            .Height = 150 ' Adjust the height as needed
            imageHeight = .Height
        End With
        
        'If cumulativeTop + imageHeight > 980 Then
        
            'METHOD 1
            ' Add a new section for each image
            'Dim newSection As Object
            'Set newSection = wordDoc.Sections.Add
            'newSection.PageSetup.SectionStart = 1 ' Start on a new page

            'METHOD 2
            'wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add.Range.InsertAfter vbNewLine & Chr(12)
            
            'METHOD 3
            ' Insert a paragraph after the image
            'wordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
            'wordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.SpaceAfter = 12
            'wordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertBreak Type:=7 ' 7 represents wdPageBreak
            
        'End If

        wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add.SpaceAfter = 28

        productName = "Product Name: " & excelWorksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
        productLink = "Product Link: " & excelWorksheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
        
        With wordDoc.Content
            .InsertAfter productName & vbCrLf & productLink & vbCrLf
            .Font.Size = 14
            .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        End With
        
        ' Add spacing between productName and productLink pair of text
        wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add.SpaceAfter = imageHeight - 84
        
        cumulativeTop = cumulativeTop + 150 + 28
        
        
        
    Next i
    
    
    
    ' Clean up
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    Set excelWorksheet = Nothing
    Set excelWorkbook = Nothing
    Set excelApp = Nothing
    Set image = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

My output is as such:
[Figure shows my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhOIt.png)

Perfect! I achieved my aims beautifully! But for one...

---

If you read my code above, you would realise an entire section was commented off.

```
'If cumulativeTop + imageHeight > 980 Then
        
            'METHOD 1
            ' Add a new section for each image
            'Dim newSection As Object
            'Set newSection = wordDoc.Sections.Add
            'newSection.PageSetup.SectionStart = 1 ' Start on a new page

            'METHOD 2
            'wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add.Range.InsertAfter vbNewLine & Chr(12)
            
            'METHOD 3
            ' Insert a paragraph after the image
            'wordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
            'wordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.SpaceAfter = 12
            'wordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertBreak Type:=7 ' 7 represents wdPageBreak

            'cumulativeTop=0
            
        'End If
```

When images were loaded into my document, it worked well. But when more was added and the entire page was occupied, the newer images didn't load onto a new page but remained at the bottom of the existing page. You couldn't make it out quite clearly in the output picture above since the images were on top of each other but you can see it in the picture below(I moved the pictures this time):

[Figure shows my real output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j1DE.png)

So, with the batch of code above (the code in if statement), whenever the sum of the cumulative .Top value of the images (where the newest image will be positioned) and the image's height is more than the page's height which is approximately 980 points, a page break will be applied and newer images will be loaded onto the next page to prevent overlapping.

I used 3 different methods as can be seen above but none worked on the images. BUT it worked for the text. As you can see, the images are still at the same location(or actually at the top since cumulativeTop variable is set to 0 to reset it).

[Figure shows output after page break applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkxaq.png)

---

Why doesn't the page break work? Can you all help me achieve this? Thank you very much in advance!

P.S. I cannot embedded images because I do not have 10 reputation points. Please do view the image through the Stack Imgur links.

---

Comment: I would use a table with two columns - place the image into the first column, text into the second - then page breaks are no issue.

Comment: I see. I guess that will be more efficient than using word wrapping. I assume the page break does not work due to the use of the Shapes property in:

Set image = wordDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=excelWorksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
            Width:=-1, Height:=-1)

If the image was an inline shape, the page break would work (I guess). But of course, the text cannot be positioned properly to the right of the image due to lack of text wrap

Comment: Exactly - therefore: use a table! You can vertically center the text in the second column.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. But I will still need answers to this question to better understand how VBA works. I am curious how would we go about setting page break for images that are not inline objects. It is good knowledge on how certain properties work.